# Jenkins error :54: expecting anything but ''\n''; got it anyway

Tags: shell, jenkins, jenkins-groovy

I am using below apache groovy script in jenkins pipeline to deploy my artifact(dev.ear) to server. I have embedded shell script in groovy to securely copy dev.ear from jenkins slave to target server(unix server).

```
node('linux') {
    stage('Checkout/Download/Deploy') {
        timeout(time: 30, unit: 'MINUTES') {

        def ziptmp = '.ziptmp'
        output = sh returnStdout: true, script:"/bin/rm -rf ${ziptmp}; /bin/mkdir ${ziptmp}; cd ${ziptmp}; /usr/bin/unzip -qq ${tempdir}/${artifactFilename}; ls -ltr; echo *; 
            if [ -e dev.ear ]
            then
                scp dev.ear lsfi@${serverName57}:/apps/wls/dev/applications;
                echo "COPIED DEV ARTIFACT TO SERVER"

            else
                echo "DEPLOYMENT PACKAGE DOESNT CONTAIN DEV ARTIFACT"
            fi"
        echo "RESULT::: ${output}"
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the below error when I trigger Jenkins job

```
WorkflowScript: 54: expecting anything but ''\n''; got it anyway @ line 54, column 171.
   ctFilename}; ls -ltr; echo *;
```

I removed new lines in the shell script and updated code as below :

```
def ziptmp = '.ziptmp'
output = sh returnStdout: true, script:"/bin/rm -rf ${ziptmp}; /bin/mkdir ${ziptmp}; cd ${ziptmp}; /usr/bin/unzip -qq ${tempdir}/${artifactFilename}; ls -ltr; echo *; if [ -e dev.ear ] then scp dev.ear lsfi@${serverName57}:/apps/wls/dev/applications; fi;"
echo "RESULT::: ${output}"
```

But I am getting the below error :

```
line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
```

How to resolve this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Groovy doesn't like a newline in a GString. According to [the Grails cookbook](http://grails.asia/groovy-multiline-string) you can make multiline Strings using either `'''Your multiline String'''` or `"""Your multiline ${GString}"""`.

I'm not very sure on bash syntax, but you also seem to be missing a semicolon after `if [ -e dev.ear ]` according to [these docs](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-6.html).

Putting it all together:

```
output = sh returnStdout: true, script: """/bin/rm -rf ${ziptmp}; /bin/mkdir ${ziptmp}; cd ${ziptmp}; /usr/bin/unzip -qq ${tempdir}/${artifactFilename}; ls -ltr; echo *; 
    if [ -e dev.ear ];
    then
        scp dev.ear lsfi@${serverName57}:/apps/wls/dev/applications;
        echo "COPIED DEV ARTIFACT TO SERVER"
    else
        echo "DEPLOYMENT PACKAGE DOESNT CONTAIN DEV ARTIFACT"
    fi"
echo "RESULT::: ${output}"""
```